# iOS: When will each initializer be used for table cells? init, initWithFrame, initWithCoder, initWithStyle

Tags: ios

I recently did a programmatic alloc/init of a table cell subclass, and with some NSLog's, I was able to learn that pretty much all of the initializers were being called even though all I did was alloc/init, if I recall correctly.

init
initWithStyle

What is the logic to this?
Which one calls which?

Comment: please post code for a more specific answer.  calling init will launch the init methods so im not sure exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Everything traces back to `init`. A `UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `NSObject`, so it has an `init` method.

`initWithFrame` is deprecated, and has been for some time (since iOS 3). You shouldn't be using it.

It was replaced in iOS 3 with `initWithStyle`, which you use to indicate what style of cell you'd like to create.

`initWithCoder` is another `NSObject` method, part of the `NSCoding` protocol. Again, you can see it in `UITableViewCell` because it is a sub-class of `NSObject`. `initWithCoder` is used to unarchive an object (perhaps you have saved an object directly to a file, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell which calls which by looking at the order in which the log messages appear.

A common pattern in Objective-C code is to have a "designated initialiser", which actually creates and returns a configured instance of the class. All of the other initialisers call the designated initialiser with fixed values for some of the parameters that weren't specified by the caller, or provide further configuration once the designated initialiser has returned.